# How does @Lazy and proxy bean affect Circular Dependencies in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, lazy-loading, circular-dependency

Let's look at the following example

```
    @Service
    class AServiceImpl{

         @Autowired
         BService bservice
    }

    @Service
    class BServiceImpl{

         @Autowired
         AService aservice
    }
```

I know the Spring uses three-level cache to solve Circular Dependency issues. When A is being initialized and B is being injected, Spring begins to initialize B, which needs bean of A to be injected. But A is not fully initialized yet, so B just get a reference to a non-fully initialized bean of A from cache.

But in Spring, if AService is with a @Transactional annotation, Spring will construct an proxy Bean for A using BeanPostProcessor, and this process happens after @Autowired. This means, although B have a a reference to a non-fully initialized bean of A from cache, the reference is not pointing to the proxy bean, which doesn't seem to be correct. Is there anything wrong with my reasoning?

There is a saying the @Lazy could solve spring Circular Dependencies problem. According to my understanding, there are two types of usage of this annotation.

```
@Lazy
@Service
class AServiceImpl{

     @Autowired
     BService bservice
}
```

or

```
@Service
class BServiceImpl{

     @Lazy
     @Autowired
     AService aservice
}
```

Some explanation of this annotation says that the annotated bean will be initialized if it is referenced by another bean. But I think  whether with it or without it, "the annotated bean will always be initialized if it is referenced by another bean", so how can it solve the circular dependency problem?

Some other explanation says that the annotated bean will be initialized if its methods are invoked, this sound reasonable, but I tried and it seems to me that even if none of methods in AService is called, B can still hold the reference to the final proxy bean of AService, what is wrong with my try?

Comment: For `BeanPostProcessor`, the `Post` bit basically means "after creation" - so it's not that the `BeanPostProcessor` creates the bean, but it is responsible for processing (initialising) beans after they have been created.  So B's reference to A remains valid.   Also useful in these sorts of scenarios is the @PostConstruct annotation, and see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393645/execution-order-of-postconstruct

Comment: @racraman if BeanPostProcessor creates a proxy bean through jdk (InvocationHandler) or cglib(MethodInterceptor), then it is not the previous bean before, it is a new bean with the previous bean as its member field (target object)

Comment: Again, `BeanPostProcessor` does NOT create a bean, it's part of initialising it.    eg, from https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp :  "`BeanPostProcessor` instances operate on bean (or object) instances. That is, the Spring IoC container instantiates a bean instance and then BeanPostProcessor instances do their work."  Note the "and THEN".

Comment: To solve circular dependency using  field injection I don't think you don't have to use @Lazy annotation

Comment: @racraman if BeanPostProcessor doesn't do the work of making a proxy bean for classes annotated with `@Transactional`, how and when is the proxy bean made and referenced?

Comment: @OrçunÇolak then what is your opinion on my question?

Comment: The serviceA bean (with its normal set of proxies) is created by the IOC container along with all the other beans, and that’s all that’s needed.  Calling “saveStuff()” on a Transactional bean doesn’t require any special additional proxy bean or facade to do the job.  Rather, spring’s standard proxies do not only reference the target bean, but also maintain “chains” of “interceptor” methods to call before/after the target’s methods are called.  Specifying @Transactional simply adds the transaction state methods to these chains.

Comment: @racraman I meant the aservice auto wired in BService  refer to the proxy bean but not the original bean, don't you think so?

Comment: Of course - Spring puts proxies to satisfy the Autowire for both AService and BService, so neither refer directly to the actual bean.   I would not imagine the proxies created for AService would be significantly different from that for Bservice - as I say, the functionality of the Transactional marker would be achieved through interceptors rather than by a different type of proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is inside a [constructor](https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring)

```
@Autowired
public AService(@Lazy BService bservice) {
    this.bservice = bservice;
}
```

> instead of fully initializing the bean, it will create a proxy to inject it into the other bean. The injected bean will only be fully created when it’s first needed.

Comment: I'm actually asking about the rationale/mechanism, not the alternative solution.